# Bootstrap tooltip triggering on focus of input element and next input element

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a tooltip on a input element in a table. I want to trigger that tooltip on focus of either that input element or the input element in the adjacent table data.

Here is my HTML structure

```html
<td class="feat-attr filled">
    <select data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Select the type of keyboard" name="attr_text">
        <option value="">Not Available</option>
        <option value="129">Normal Keypad</option>
        <option value="128">QWERTY</option>
        <option value="709" selected>Touchscreen</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td class="feat-text">
    <input type="text" name="text" value="Touchscreen"/>
</td>
```

The element having the tooltip can either be `select` element or an `input` element. Here is my JS code to trigger the tooltip

```js
$(function () { $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip({'trigger':'focus'}); });
```

This works fine for the input element with the tooltip. How can I show the tooltip when the user focuses on the adjacent input element?

Answer (score -1):

this is correct answer

```
<select data-toggle="tooltip"  data-trigger="focus"
        data-placement="bottom" title="Select 
        the type of keyboard" name="attr_text">


data-trigger="focus"//trigger tooltip event for focus
data-trigger="hover"//trigger tooltip event for hover
data-trigger="active"//trigger tooltip event for active
```

check is link 
[click here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)